# Trying to write a jQuery-CSS drop down menu. When menu is clicked other elements move around

Tags: jquery, html, css

Its somewhat complicated to explain (or maybe I'm just feeling incoherent because of my frustration) so I have made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YmbMJ/

In the results section if you scroll all the way over to the top right and click on "USERNAME" a menu drops down but when this menu drops down 2 of the elements in my navigation also drops with it.  I've tried playing around with the CSS position tags and z-index but still no luck. Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: i dont see any dropdown menu when i click username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `position` property of the drop-down menu to `absolute` it will remove it from the regular flow of the webpage and it can be shown over the nav-bar. Just set the CSS of the `#corner_menu` element like this:

```
#corner_menu {
    position : absolute !important;
    top      : 50px !important;
    left     : 950px !important;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YmbMJ/1/

I would normally use `right` instead of `left` since the element is located on the right side of the page but in this case I didn't want to alter any more of your CSS as it needs to be for `right` to work properly. The parent element (`#header`) needs to have its `position` set to something other than `static` (like `relative`) and also needs it's width changed to reach both sides of the page.

Comment: Thank you, this has been much help but when I change the CSS of corner menu it looks alot better but I still am not able to align the menu that pops up along with the user name. I've added a position to header and changed the width to 100%. Then I changed the #corner_menu CSS right to 0. But still have the same problem. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/zakiaziz/YmbMJ/4/

Can you go into a little more detail as to what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use position absolute to not effect the other divs around the menu

I think it would be around the div below but will prob need a bit off fiddling

```
#header ul{
   background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: changing that does fix the problem of the 2 last items in my navigation from moving but it also created the problem of having the menu pop up in a random place. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/zakiaziz/YmbMJ/3/